# $sum on same field value

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("593fbefd0b0cbbe593cd89d3"),
    "coins" : "220",
    "reasonId" : ObjectId("593500980b0cbbe593cd722c"),
    "empId" : ObjectId("592eb2e224da300ca89b05d5"),
    "clubId" : ObjectId("592d6bea7ab7f62d58001329")
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59413b170b0cbbe593cd8b46"),
    "coins" : "220",
    "reasonId" : ObjectId("593500980b0cbbe593cd722c"),
    "empId" : ObjectId("592eb2e224da300ca89b05d5"),
    "clubId" : ObjectId("592d6bea7ab7f62d58001329")
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("593fbefd0b0cbbe593cd89d5"),
    "reasonId" : ObjectId("5934ffb80b0cbbe593cd722a"),
    "empId" : ObjectId("5912e5747f83352face7e431"),
    "coins" : "100",
    "clubId" : ObjectId("592d6bea7ab7f62d58001329")
}
```

I want to sum the coins for single empId based on clubId.The employee's coins should be based on one club only, How to do aggregation on this??

Comment: When the fields are "strings" and not numbers you are going to find that difficult with the aggregation framework. I suggest you fix your data. Then do some basic research at least. This is not hard.

Comment: You want to fetch all records where `clubId = something`, then sum the `coins` field? First, make `coins` an integer not a string, to save yourself unnecessary pain. Then, show us what you have tried so far .. This is a very simple problem that a [basic google search](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44549077/edit) can probably answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

let's assume your colleciton is "employee" but convert coins to string first

```
db.employee.aggregate(
{
   $match:{
        "empId" : ObjectId("5912e5747f83352face7e431")
   }
},
{
   $group:{
        _id: "$clubId",
        sumCoins : {$sum: "$coins"}
   }
}
)
```